# Change Permanently Session System Variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, settings, global-variables, session-variables

I added this line to my.ini

```
wait_timeout=2000000
```

When I type

```
show global variables
```

It prints wait_timeout=2000000,

but when I type

```
show variables
```

It prints wait_timeout=28800

I can set with

```
set wait_timeout=2000000
```

But I do not want to set it all the time manually.

Do you have any suggestion to set permanently session system variable?

Comment: Remember to restart MySQL after changing my.ini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to check the interactive_timeout is set also - regular client connections are probably picking up your new setting, but when you check it manually using an interactive client, MySQL will set the timeout from this setting:

> On thread startup, the session
>   wait_timeout value is initialized from
>   the global wait_timeout value or from
>   the global interactive_timeout value,
>   depending on the type of client (as
>   defined by the CLIENT_INTERACTIVE
>   connect option to
>   mysql_real_connect()). See also
>   interactive_timeout.

[See manual for details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout).